# Javascript - Help understanding variable behaviour

Tags: javascript, closures

Take the two examples below. In both examples, the variable `i` is assigned as 0 through 9. In the first example, by the time the timeout function is called, `i` has already been assigned the value of 9. I do not know the value of `i` when the timeout was set.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var callback = function() {
        alert('The first test returns: ' + i);
    };

    if(i === 0) setTimeout(callback, 2000);
}
```

In the second option, we are able to persist the value of `i` by passing it into a new context (please correct me if this terminology is incorrect).

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var callback = (function(i) {
        return function() {
            alert('The second test returns: ' + i);
        }
    })(i);

    if(i === 0) setTimeout(callback, 2000);
}
```

The second example gives me the value I expect, `0` - so how does this work as far as garbage collection goes? At what point will the GC delete this value? At the end of the callback function? Or will there be some sort of memory leak?

Comment: That's not the purpose of this question, I was simply creating an asynchronous mechanism for the purpose of the explanation.

Comment: i think setInterval is the better way to approach things..will reduce your code to half

Comment: You're completely missing the point of this.

Comment: @MESSIAH OP is trying to understand _why_ `i` is behaving the way it is, he's not trying to fix it or make it more efficient.

Comment: Note that either way JS doesn't have block scope, so using `var` inside the loop like that actually declares `callback` in the scope of the surrounding function (or as a global if there is no surrounding function).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, `callback` is the function `function(){alert('...' + i);}`, where `i` is the variable in the scope where `callback` is defined, i.e. `i` in `for(var i = 0; ...)`.

Even though `setTimeout(callback, 2000)` is called when `i` is `0`, after 2000ms, which is sufficient time to run through whole `for` loop, `i` will become 10, and when `callback` is called, `The first test returns: 10` will be shown.

However, in the second example where a closure is made, `callback` itself is still `function(){alert('...' + i);}`, but since argument `i` in an anonymous function shadows its parent scope, `i` in `callback` is argument `i` in the anonymous function, not the `i` in `for(var i = 0; ...)`.

Since JavaScript uses call-by-value, that `i` will be 'fixed' when `callback` is set by `(function(i){...}(i))`, which makes an anonymous function with argument `i` then apply it immediately by value `i` (in `for(var i ...)`).

GC have no role in here. (Different behavior by GC - except memory usage and timing - means there's a bug in GC.)

Comment: This is exactly as I suspected. Great explanation, thank you. So I run no risk of memory problems in long running code using the closure then? (Provided the for-loop has reasonable bounds?)

Comment: I don't know much about garbage collectors, but I suspect (not certain) that closure does not make a lot of difference, except that there might be some information about scope that occupies some memory.

Comment: It should be garbage collected in a similar manner to any other object, i.e., once there are no references to the functions anywhere (after the timeout runs) there's no need to keep its closure scope around.